# how to seal or fill in 4" round vent hole from inside house to outside of brick

Tags: concrete, vent, brick, hole

I am removing a 4 or 6 inch round venting pipe from above the stove microwave that goes out the side of my kitchen inside wall and goes through the drywall and brick to outside.

So I want to fill in this 4-6 inch round hole and about 10 or so inches deep.  How would I fill this in from outside to inside so there will be no cold coming into my house? What material should be used to fill in the hole and what material should be used to finisnh the inside of the wall and what material to finish the brick ?

Comment: why don't you use the same materials as the wall?

Comment: Whatever you use, make it **reversible without great difficulty.** You may regret the lack of a proper vent for the stove, and punching holes in brick walls is painful.

Comment: Are you planning on venting the nuke in some different fashion?

Comment: Pink fiberglass insulation can be stuffed in it.   And it is reversible.

Comment: Rockwool, perhaps. Fiberglass, I would not.

Answer (score 1):

*I think you'd be better served to put a proper **damper** on the vent so that it does not allow cold drafts in, while still functioning as a vent. Having lived with unvented kitchens, they are terrible unless you don't cook at all, and your stove is just a useless object taking up space. If your stove is gas, removing the vent **may** be a code violation and is definitely not good sense.*

Anyway, in the interests of you, or a future owner, being able to re-open the vent easily when a vent is wanted again, since putting holes in brick walls is a huge pain, I'd suggest a minimalist plug that won't be difficult to remove.

Cut a disc of cementboard (or quarry tile) to fit the outer hole, give it a faux-brick paintjob (the quarry tile being more-or-less the right color for most brick is a feature, here) or apply thin slices of brick if that sort of appearance factor is a big deal to you, and caulk it into place (using a "masonry" caulking compound) in the outer wall. Give it a day or two to cure.

Mist the inside of the hole with water and apply less sprayfoam than you *think* you'll need to the inside of the plug, and wait for it to expand (give it a couple hours - the first bit is quick, but it can keep growing slowly for a while.) Re-apply until the hole is full. Cut back the face of the cured foam to let you put in a drywall plug for the inner face of the hole.

Consider placing a decorative tile (or something) in the center of it if you'll be doing a "make it disappear" job blending with the wall surface, so it won't be too hard to find. Normal drywall-patch repair other than that detail - tape and compound, small knife, wait for it to cure/dry, scrape off any high points, refill using a wider knife, repeat until you're happy with it.

Comment: do we remove the old venting out of the hole before we spray foam it iwould think we should or there might be a liitle gap between outer side of vent and inner side of brick

Comment: Your question stated that you were removing it.